# oauth2 token request failure with bad client_id

Tags: oauth2

I'm submitting a curl command to get an oauth token and it fails with a bad client_id. What am I missing

I setup an Auth. Provider and used MTest as mu consumer key and MRestTest as my Consumer Secret.

I execute the following curl and get an error for a bad client id.
Am I using the wrong thing for my client_id??

curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=MTest" -d "client_secret=MRestTest" -d "username=user@ourorg.com" -d "password=userpw"

Comment: You would need to create a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5) and use the Client ID and Secret from there.

Comment: So this needs two parts? An auth provider setup and a connected app? The connected apps I see do not have a client_id or client_secret only auth providers have these fields. I also do not see a way to create a connected app

Comment: That was the magic Aayush. Didn't scroll down far enough to see that part I needed. Thanks. If you want to make that an answer I will acknowledge it and give you credit

Comment: Great that it worked. I'll move it to the answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5) and use the Client ID and Secret from there.